# Is there an algorithm the rank matches of Set A in Set B, that's not total_count or pct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

So I want to rank matches, but total_count and percentage have some short comings. Something that has 1/1 match is 100%, but is less valuable that something that has 20/25 matches(even though it's a lower %). And something that has 100/5,000 matches is less valuable than something that has 20/20 matches even though the total_count is higher. Is there a good formula/equation the can be used that accounts for this?

So i've tried both `total_count` and `pct` based sorting and both work reasonably well in the middle of the data, but the top and bottom are usually not helpful.

For context. I'm trying to match Spotify playlists that have the most songs in them that a user has liked. 1 out of 1 song is not helpful. Neither is 20 out of 500. I need some mix of pct and total_count, perhaps probability of this specific match happening?.

Comment: I think approaching a problem like this is more of an artform than exact science. This is because there in an infinity of approaches that would filfill these requirements. Different games and sports have different scoring/ranking systems. Maybe it would be useful to check them out. But looking at your requirements, it seems like we want to measure someone's skill. The ratio of wins and losses determines this skill, and the total number of games played determines some kind of error term for the skill ... One thing that comes to my mind is Student's T-test, but of course it's a bit complicated.

Comment: @ThomasShelby added additional context.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks, I'll look into those. I added additional info to my post for context of my problem.

Comment: One way to see this is that you want to compare two samples of two different random variables. The random variables follow the binomial distribution, and you want to find out which one has the largest expected value. It could be that for the first you have $20$ samples, and for the other only $5$. Therefore, an error term is important. You could calculate the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. The number of samples is $n$. Now the $95~\%$ confidence interval for the mean is
$$
\mu \pm \frac{1.96 \sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
You could try out something like this ...

Comment: Also this could give some ideas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair